# Counting the values in a dataframe column based on user input

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, input, count

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences in a column of my dataframe based on the user input:

```
ID   State        Comments
1    California   Outsourced
2    Maryland     NA
3    Maryland     Outsourced
```

So, if the user were to enter "Maryland", Python would return "The number of occurrences in Maryland is 2." I was having trouble finding answers for this online, so this is how I tried to do it:

```
state_input = input("Enter the state: ")
while True:
    if state_input == df['State']:
       df['State'].eq(state_input).sum()
    break
if cases > 0:
    print(cases)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""ID   State        Comments
1    California   Outsourced
2    Maryland     NA
3    Maryland     Outsourced"""), sep='\s+')

state_input = input("Enter the state: ")
cases = (df['State'] == state_input).sum()
if cases:
    print(f"The number of occurrences in {state_input} is {cases}")
```

Output:

```
Enter the state: Maryland
The number of occurrences in Maryland is 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's create a dataframe like you said

```
import pandas as pd
dic = {'ID':[1,2,3],'State':['California','Maryland','Maryland'], 'Comments':['Outsourced','NA','Outsourced']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
df
```

this might help

```py
state_input = input("Enter the state: ")

if state_input in df.State.values:
    print(len(df[df['State'] == state_input ]))
```